# How to configure GGLContext in iOS app when there are more than 1 GoogleService-Info.plist in the project?

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

I have a common workspace for 7 apps that we release in 7 AppStore countries. Each of them have different bundle identifiers and hence it requires me to create 7 apps on the Google Dev console and generate different GoogleService-Info.plist files. How do I parse these files?

[[GGLContext sharedInstance] configureWithError:&configureError];]
This configures the Google context: parses the GoogleService-Info.plist, and initializes the services that have entries in the file.

How is this possible when I have multiple files?

Comment: Your can have multiple different plist files, and each of them can be located in specific project or target. So that it will use the information from a specific plist file from specific project or target.

Comment: Thanks ztan. I have a single target for all these regions. So I wrote a build script to edit the contents of GooleService-Info.plist and maintain the variables in build configurations.